# Ansible Traversing nested list output from find module

Tags: python, dictionary, ansible, nested, find

I'm creating a disk clean-up role using the Ansible find module and data from a dictionary to run the cleanup. In addition to getting rid of old files, files need to get archived to S3 before they are removed from the disk. I'm pasting the "cleanup" dictionary setup below

```yaml
   cleanUp:
     data1.archive:
       paths: '/opt/data/appdata'
       patterns: 
          - '*.csv'
       archive_bucket: prod-appdata
     data-targz.archive:
       paths: '/opt/data/targz'
       patterns: 
         - '*.tar.gz'
       archive_bucket: prod-targz
```

Then in the tasks, I search for the files needing to be archived

```yaml
    - name: find files to archive before removal
      find:
        paths: '{{ item.value.paths }}'
        patterns: '{{ item.value.patterns }}'
      register: archFiles
      loop: "{{ cleanUp|dict2items }}"
```

The tricky part is parsing the results in the "archFiles" list I'm registering above.
I've managed to get the file names by adding their subelement number, but this wouldn't work in the real world. This is what I need help with. I haven't been able to get all the files in the list as well as the s3 bucket info in one loop

```yaml
    - name: search results
      debug:
        msg:
          - "key: {{ item.item.key }}"
          - "bucket: {{ item.item.value.archive_bucket }}"
          - "{{ item.files[0].path }}"
          - "{{ item.files[1].path }}"
          - "{{ item.files[2].path }}"
      loop: "{{ archFiles.results }}"
```

My ultimate goal is to create a new dictionary in the playbook where I grab each S3 bucket and path and upload the list of files to them. I'm not 100% sure what that dictionary would look like. But I think I can get there if I could figure out a way to list the key, S3 bucket info, and a list of all files found (without using the element number). Something like:

```yaml
  msg:
  - 'key: data1.archive'
  - 'bucket: prod-appdata'
  - <path>/file0
  - <path>/file1
  - <path>/file2
  - <path>/file3
  - <path>/etc....
```

When I run what I have the output looks like this: (truncated a bit for brevity)

```yaml
TASK [search results] ****************************************************

  msg:
  - 'key: data-targz.archive'
  - 'bucket: prod-targz'
  - /opt/data/targz/20201023_uat4.tar.gz
  - /opt/data/targz/20201023_uat5.tar.gz
  - /opt/data/targz/20201023_uat6.tar.gz
  msg:
  - 'key: data1.archive'
  - 'bucket: prod-appdata'
  - /opt/data/appdata/20201023_size_0_10_testuat2
  - /opt/data/appdata/20201023_size_0_10_testuat
  - /opt/data/appdata/20201023_uat3
```

**UPDATE**

With help from Vladimir (below) I'm creating a new dictionary with set_fact which comes very close to doing what I want:

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        arch_dict: "{{ arch_dict|default({})|combine({item: (_bucket, _list)}) }}"
      loop: "{{ archFiles.results|json_query('[].item.key') }}"
      vars:
        _query_bucket: "[?item.key == '{{ item }}'].item.value.archive_bucket"
        _bucket: "{{ archFiles.results|json_query(_query_bucket) }}"
        _query: "[?item.key == '{{ item }}'].files[].path"
        _list: "{{ archFiles.results|json_query(_query) }}"

    - name: print arch_dict 
      debug:
        var: arch_dict
      loop: "{{ arch_dict|dict2items }}"
```

truncated Output from debug (above):

```yaml
  arch_dict:
    data1.archive:
     - - prod-appdata
     - - /opt/axioma/data/opt/20201023_size_0_10_testuat2
       - /opt/axioma/data/opt/20201023_size_0_10_testuat
       - /opt/axioma/data/opt/20201023_uat3

     data-targz.archive:
     - - prod-targz
     - - /opt/data/20201023_uat4.tar.gz
       - /opt/data/20201023_uat5.tar.gz
       - /opt/data/20201023_uat6.tar.gz
```

The first item in each output, following the key, is the S3 bucket I need to send the files to. The rest of the items are the files.

I need to be able to reference these independently ... something like:

```yaml
{{ item.value.bucket }}
```

and

```yaml
{{ item.value.files }}
```

But, the only thing I've been able to do is to get key/values. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Post example of the expected result. How should the directory look like? [edit] your question and make it [mre]. The problem here is parsing the results of *find*.  Make the case **minimal** and get rid of the irrelevant balast (patterns, type, age, ... selecting archive keys, ...).

Comment: Thanks Vladimir...doing my best.

Answer (score 0):

For example, given the files

```yaml
shell> tree no_archive/
no_archive/
├── 1.csv
├── 2.csv
└── 3.csv

0 directories, 3 files
shell> tree appdata/
appdata/
├── 1.dat
├── 2.dat
└── 3.dat

0 directories, 3 files
```

and the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    cleanUp:
      csv_application:
        paths: no_archive
      data1_archive:
        paths: appdata
  tasks:
    - find:
        paths: '{{ item.value.paths }}'
      register: archFiles
      loop: "{{ cleanUp|dict2items }}"
    - set_fact:
        _dict: "{{ _dict|default({})|combine({item: _list}) }}"
      loop: "{{ archFiles.results|json_query('[].item.key') }}"
      vars:
        _query: "[?item.key == '{{ item }}'].files[].path"
        _list: "{{ archFiles.results|json_query(_query) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  _dict:
    csv_application:
    - no_archive/3.csv
    - no_archive/2.csv
    - no_archive/1.csv
    data1_archive:
    - appdata/1.dat
    - appdata/3.dat
    - appdata/2.dat
```

---

Q: *"**Have the S3 bucket info in the new dictionary**"*

A: For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    cleanUp:
      data1_archive:
        paths: appdata
        archive_bucket: prod-appdata
        archive_path: archives/appdata
      data_targz_archive:
        paths: no_archive
        archive_bucket: prod-targz
        archive_path: archives/targz
  tasks:
    - find:
        paths: '{{ item.value.paths }}'
      register: archFiles
      loop: "{{ cleanUp|dict2items }}"
    - set_fact:
        _dict: "{{ _dict|default({})|combine({item: _value|first}) }}"
      loop: "{{ archFiles.results|json_query('[].item.key') }}"
      vars:
        _query: "[?item.key == '{{ item }}'].{paths: files[].path,
                                              archive_bucket: item.value.archive_bucket,
                                              archive_path: item.value.archive_path}"
        _value: "{{ archFiles.results|json_query(_query) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  _dict:
    data1_archive:
      archive_bucket: prod-appdata
      archive_path: archives/appdata
      paths:
      - appdata/1.dat
      - appdata/3.dat
      - appdata/2.dat
    data_targz_archive:
      archive_bucket: prod-targz
      archive_path: archives/targz
      paths:
      - no_archive/3.csv
      - no_archive/2.csv
      - no_archive/1.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir! I'm trying to dissect what you posted so I can also have the S3 bucket info in the new dictionary....but I'm much closer now.

Comment: You're welcome, Brandon! If this is what you were looking for [edit] the question, fit it to this answer, and make it [mre], please.